# Nifi Streaming from Json file

Tags: json, csv, apache-nifi

I have a Json file that is constantly updated with new items. 
Using Nifi I want to create a flow that live extract content from this one Json file, then make an output file that can be a CSV for example so that then I can do some analysis in Excel with it.
I am new to Nifi, so can you suggest some process flows for this event? 
Anything to get me started will be more than helpful.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of operations to be performed for this flow, I can offer some approaches to tackle each:

- Retrieve updated JSON file: To continuously get the file (if it has changed), you can use a ListFile processor wired to a FetchFile processor, with the FetchFile property "Completion Strategy" set to "None". This will keep the JSON file on the file system. If the JSON file is continually regenerated, you can use "Move" or "Delete" for the strategy.
- Extract JSON values (if the content of the file is replaced on change): If the value(s) you're looking for are in the same place (i.e. the same JSONPath expression all the time), you can use EvaluateJsonPath to extract the value(s) into attributes. To get the values back into the content (for converting to CSV), you can use ReplaceText (with Expression Language) to put the attributes back in the content.
- Extract JSON values (if new items are inserted into the document): If the items are part of an array, you can use SplitJson to produce flow files for each element in the document. This will involve more complex processing as you will likely want to ignore elements you have already seen. You may be able to use ReplaceText (see above) to put certain values in content, then Put/FetchDistributedMapCache to check if the array elements have already been processed.
- Output CSV: For each flow file containing the attribute(s) you want as CSV fields, you can use ReplaceText to generate a line of CSV. Then you can use MergeContent to create a full CSV file. Note this won't have a header, you can use a final ReplaceText to insert the header row followed by the incoming content. Then PutFile will write the CSV file to disk.